# DRF Cannot assign must be instance error while testing

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am very new to Django and especially to testing.

I am trying to test a view which retrieves a resource object and creates a game round and gamesession object (in the get request).

This is what my tests look like:
**test_views.py**

```
class GameViewTests(APITestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        self.resource = {'hash_id': '1404cc769fa538fab1b65b9cad201eca'}
        self.user = CustomUser.objects.create(username="carina")
        self.gametype = Gametype.objects.create(name="imageLabeler", rounds=5, round_duration=60, enabled=True),
        self.gamesession = Gamesession.objects.create(user=self.user, gametype=self.gametype, created=datetime.now())
        self.gameround = Gameround.objects.create(user=self.user, gamesession=self.gamesession,
                                                  created=datetime.now(), score=0)
        self.game_data = {'gametype': self.gametype,
                                 'gamesession': self.gamesession,
                                 'gameround': self.gameround,
                                 'resource': self.resource}
        self.response = self.client.get('http://localhost:8000/api/game/',
                                        self.game_data,
                                        format="json")

    def test_get(self):
        self.client = APIClient()
        response = self.client.get('http://localhost:8000/api/game/')
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

When I run my test, I get the ValueError: Cannot assign "(<Gametype: imageLabeler>,)": "Gamesession.gametype" must be a "Gametype" instance.

How can I make my test pass?

Update:
This is my View:

```
class GameView(APIView):

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        gametype = Gametype.objects.all().get(name="imageLabeler")
        gametype_serializer = GametypeSerializer(gametype)

        current_score = 0
        if not isinstance(request.user, CustomUser):
            current_user_id = 1
        else:
            current_user_id = request.user.pk

        gamesession = Gamesession.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                                 gametype=gametype,
                                                 created=datetime.now())

        random_resource = Resource.objects.all().order_by('?').first()
        first_resource_serializer = ResourceSerializer(random_resource)

        gameround = Gameround.objects.create(user_id=current_user_id,
                                             gamesession=gamesession,
                                             created=datetime.now(),
                                             score=current_score)

        gameround_serializer = GameroundSerializer(gameround)

        start_time = gamesession.created
        # now = timezone.now()
        end_of_game = start_time + timedelta(minutes=5)
        # request.session.set_expiry(300)
        if not datetime.now() == end_of_game:
            return Response({'resource': first_resource_serializer.data, 'gameround': gameround_serializer.data,})

        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_408_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        tag_serializer = TagSerializer(data=request.data)
        tagging_serializer = TaggingSerializer(data=request.data)
        gameround_id = request.data.get('gameround_id')
        gameround = Gameround.objects.all().get(id=gameround_id)

        # time where the gameround was created
        start_time = gameround.created
        # time 5 mins after gameround was created
        end_of_game = start_time + timedelta(seconds=20)
        if not datetime.now() == end_of_game:
            if tagging_serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
                tagging_serializer.save(tagging=request.data)
                return Response({"status": "success", "data": tagging_serializer.data}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
            else:
                return Response({"status": "error", "data": tag_serializer.errors}, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
        else:
            return Response(status=status.HTTP_408_REQUEST_TIMEOUT)
```

This is the traceback of the error:

```
ERROR [2022-02-08 23:32:20,856] Internal Server Error: /api/game/
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/exception.py", line 47, in inner
    response = get_response(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 181, in _get_response
    response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py", line 54, in wrapped_view
    return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/views/generic/base.py", line 70, in view
    return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 509, in dispatch
    response = self.handle_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 469, in handle_exception
    self.raise_uncaught_exception(exc)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 480, in raise_uncaught_exception
    raise exc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/rest_framework/views.py", line 506, in dispatch
    response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/api/src/artigo_api/frontend/views/game_rest_views.py", line 155, in get
    gametype = Gametype.objects.get(name="imageLabeler")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/manager.py", line 85, in manager_method
    return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 435, in get
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
frontend.models.Gametype.DoesNotExist: Gametype matching query does not exist.
```

Comment: include the full traceback of error in your post

Comment: Isn't it too long? I have about 30 tests.

Comment: can you post the traceback of any one.

Comment: Can you share your view?

Comment: I added it now.

Comment: In line with `gametype = Gametype.objects.all().get(name="imageLabeler")` try to remove `.all()`. So this line should look like `gametype = Gametype.objects.get(name="imageLabeler")`

Comment: Changed it. View still works but tests still fail.

Comment: it would be easier with the traceback of one of your tests; can you post it?

Comment: Ok, I posted it. Not sure if this is what you mean though.

Comment: It looks like my answer fixed your first problem ? Now you have another one?

Answer (score 0):

```
    raise self.model.DoesNotExist(
frontend.models.Gametype.DoesNotExist: Gametype matching query does not exist.
```

You don't have `Gametype` object with `name` `imageLabeler` in database.

you should catch [`DoesNotExist`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/exceptions/#objectdoesnotexist) error to avoid program crash:

```py
try:
    gt = Gametype.objects.get(name="imageLabeler")
except Gametype.DoesNotExist:
    print('Boom boom! here is no imageLabeler in DB')
    return Response(status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

And your another problem is you creating object with name `labeler`:

```
self.gametype = Gametype.objects.create(name="labeler", rounds=5, round_duration=60, enabled=True)
```

But trying to get `imageLabeler`:

```
gametype = Gametype.objects.all().get(name="imageLabeler")
```

Comment: I have put this in the view now.I am getting the same error though.

Comment: here is many errors in code (added explanation in answer). And it is impossible to get `same error` if you updated `try→except` part correctly